# Angular import * into module declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a file that has all my components like this:

components.ts

```
export { ComponentA } from '../some/path/a.component';
export { ComponentB } from '../some/path/b.component';
export { ComponentC } from '../some/path/c.component';
// ... more here
```

In my module file, I have this:

components.module.ts

```
import { ComponentA } from '../some/path/components';
import { ComponentB } from '../some/path/components';
import { ComponentC } from '../some/path/components';
// ... more here

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

Is there a way I can just do `import * as Components from '../some/path/components'` and just put that in the `declarations` array? I have a lot of components and the list can become pretty big. In addition, every time I add a new component, I have to update both files when it would be better if I could just add it to the `components.ts` file as an export and the `import *` would take care of any new components in the module.

If someone knows, it would be greatly appreciated. Or should I even be doing it this way? If not, what would be a good practice?

I tried doing this but it returns a list of constructors for all the components and when I try to build it, Angular complains it can't determine the module for each component.

```
import * as exports from '../some/path/components';
const Components: any[] = Object.keys(exports).map(key => exports[key]);

...
delcarations: [Components]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to spread the Array into the declarations:

```
declarations: [...Components]
```

(instead Object.keys and then map, you could also simply use Object.values)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about `Object.values`! Really useful. I tried the spread operator and I get this error "ERROR in : Unexpected value 'null' declared by the module 'ComponentsModule". I tried with both my way and `Object.values`. I looked through the array and it doesn't seem to have a null value. Would you have any idea?

Comment: What is the `// ... more here` Part inside your components.ts? only more exports of components, or something more?

Comment: Just more exports of my components. Nothing else.

Comment: Okay, did you indeed try to just use `Components`, as in:
`declarations: Components`

Comment: Yes, I did. When I do that and try to build it, Angular complains it can't determine the module for each component.